# A for loop using a double conditional

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm currently trying to create a dual conditional, where, if the Cancer type (Indication) and Gene (Genes) of my data frame "mockup" both appear in another data frame called "cpg", then a new column in the mockup table has either a "yes" if both conditions are met, and a "no" if not. To illustrate this:

The mockup table has:

| Indication | Genes |
| --- | --- |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | TP53 |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | GNAQ |

And the cpg dataframe has:

| Cancer Type | Gene |
| --- | --- |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | TP53 |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | ATM |

I would like to produce a mockup table that looks like this (based on the cpg data):

| Indication | Genes | Hotspot? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | TP53 | Yes |
| Acute Myeloid Leukemia | GNAQ | No |

So far I've tried (and failed) to make a for loop with a conditional to create a vector, with the hopes of then appending this vector as a new column:

```
hotspot <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(mockup)){
  if ((mockup$Genes[i] == cpg$Gene && mockup$Indication[i] == cpg$`Cancer Type`)){
    hotspot[i] <- print("yes")
    } else {
      hotspot[i] <- print("no")
    }
}

unique(hotspot)
```

As always, any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this required?  For loops in R, as R is already vectorised, are generally avoidable.

- Base R version

```r
mockup <- read.table(text = 'Indication Genes
"Acute Myeloid Leukemia"    TP53
"Acute Myeloid Leukemia"    GNAQ', header = T)

cpg <- read.table(text = "Cancer_Type   Gene
'Acute Myeloid Leukemia'    TP53
'Acute Myeloid Leukemia'    ATM", header = T)

mockup$hotspot <- apply(mockup, 1, function(x) c('No','Yes')[(all(x %in% as.matrix(cpg)))

mockup
              Indication Genes hotspot
1 Acute Myeloid Leukemia  TP53     Yes
2 Acute Myeloid Leukemia  GNAQ      No
```

---

`dplyr` pipe friendly version

```
library(dplyr)

mockup %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(hotspot = c('No', 'Yes')[+(all(cur_data() %in% as.matrix(cpg))+1)])
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   Indication             Genes hotspot
#>   <chr>                  <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 Acute Myeloid Leukemia TP53  Yes    
#> 2 Acute Myeloid Leukemia GNAQ  No
```

Comment: Wouldn't `c("Yes", "No")[rowSums(mockup != cpg) + 1]#
[1] "Yes" "No"` be more efficient

Comment: Thanks @akrun for noticing this.  Actually I learnt this from you only.  But the answer you suggest will work in case of unequal rows in two datasets?